# How to install ClamAV using Ruby script with configuration in same script?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am using Amazon opsworks and struggling to get it working through a single script, I have created a script named `clamav.rb`. The content of script is:

```
yum_package 'clamav' do
  action :install
end

yum_package 'clamav-update' do
  action :install
end

file_names = ['/etc/freshclam.conf']

file_names.each do |file_name|

text = File.read(file_name)

 replace = text.gsub("Example", "#Example")

  # To merely print the contents of the file, use:

  puts replace

  # To write changes to the file, use:

  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts replace }

end

execute "Run Freshclam" do

  command "/usr/bin/freshclam"

end
```

When I execute the above script it stuck with an error:

```
[2016-08-01T13:02:36+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-08-01T13:02:36+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-08-01T13:02:36+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-08-01T13:02:36+00:00] ERROR: No such file or directory - /etc/freshclam.conf
[2016-08-01T13:02:36+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

but when I divide the script in two parts it run very well, like creating separate script for yum packages and separate for configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

You're being bitten by Chef's two-pass loading model. At that point in the code, the package hasn't been installed yet. Check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for more details on that, but to fix your actual problem, use the `line` cookbook which has resources for this kind of search and replace in files, which will handle sequencing correctly for you.

Comment: I am new to this, can you pls provide steps in brief

Comment: No, check out the readme for the line cookbook and it explains how to use its resources.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, below is the solution

code: replaced my older code with this

File.open('/etc/freshclam.conf', "r") do |aFile|
  if aFile
    text = File.read('/etc/freshclam.conf')
  replace = text.gsub("Example", "#Example")
  # To merely print the contents of the file, use:
  puts replace
  # To write changes to the file, use:
  File.open('/etc/freshclam.conf', "w") {|file| file.puts replace }

else
   puts "Unable to open file!"
end

end